# Convexity of sub-harmonic functions in a sector

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $F(z)$ be an analytic function in an open sector $\Sigma_{\gamma}=\{0<\arg z<\gamma<\frac{\pi}{2}\}$, and continuous to the boundary. Then $\log{|F(re^{i\theta})|}$, $z=re^{i\theta}\in \Sigma_{\gamma}$, is sub-harmonic.

My question is for each fixed $r>0$, is $\log{|F(re^{i\theta})|}$ a convex function of $0<\theta<\gamma$? i.e., do we have 
$$
|F(re^{i\theta})|\leq |F(re^{i\gamma})|^{\frac{\theta}{\gamma}}|F(r)|^{1-\frac{\theta}{\gamma}},~~0<\theta<\gamma~~?
$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be no. Take $r=1, \gamma = \pi/4$, and $\theta = \pi/6$. Let $F(z) = 1/(z-2+0.1i).$ This is analytic in the open sector since it's isolated from the pole at $z=2-0.1i.$ But you can check numerically that

$$ \vert F(e^{i\pi/6}) \vert > \vert F(e^{i\pi/4}) \vert^{2/3} \cdot \vert F(1)\vert^{1/3} $$

I'm sure someone can come up with something more elegant, but I got the idea just by drawing a picture.

Comment: Dear Phillip, I don't think your example satisfy the condition in my question.  I need the function continuously extend to the boundary. If one write laplacian in polar-coordinates in 2 dimension, then it's easy to see that for fixed $r>0$, it's convex on $\theta$

Comment: When you say sector, do you mean an unbounded sector? Or is the radius of the sector fixed? If the radius is fixed, then there is nothing wrong with my example. It is clearly continuous on the boundary of the sector.

Comment: I still don't think it works. If you take $F(z) = 1/(z-2+.01i)$, you will still get $\vert F(e^{i(\pi/6}) \vert > \vert F(e^{i(\pi/4}) \vert^{2/3} \vert F(1) \vert^{1/3}.$ And now it doesn't matter if you mean for the radius of the sector to be infinite or not, since the singularity is in the lower half-plane.

Comment: Dear Philip, I got a little confused if your updated example is true. it seems to contradict to the Hadamard's three lines lemma on the sector, which says if the analytic function is bounded and continuously extended to the boundary, it's log convex in the interior. Do you see any thing wrong here?

Comment: A sector is not bounded by parallel lines, so the three lines theorem doesn't apply.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is three lines lemma on the sector, e,g, see lemma 9 in davies paper http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022123685711032/1-s2.0-S0022123685711032-main.pdf?_tid=c20b1ecc-8eff-11e4-af5c-00000aacb361&acdnat=1419819165_4f257bb097f5d3628ce12ddf79ad8b30

Comment: You're right, there is a "three rays" theorem. But, like the three lines theorem, it applies to $\sup F$ and not the function itself.